# Removing all matching entries of 1st table from other table using merge()

Tags: r

I want to remove all matching entries of 1st table from other table using merge().

Table1:

```
ID  age
1   24
2   33
3   44
4   22
```

Table2:

```
ID  age
1   24
2   33
3   44
4   22
5   98
6   88
```

Expected Output:

```
ID  age
5   98
6   88
```

I want to make it happen by merge() for ease else dplyr options will be good as well.

Comment: Have you considered to use `anti_join()`?

Comment: No, any code(or pseudo code) will be a help.

Comment: `dplyr::anti_join(Table2, Table1)` should do it.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak and jazzurro, i have achieved this by anti_join.